# LinkedIn connections of a mutual connection not visible

Tags: linkedin

I have an issue with viewing the connections of my connections on LinkedIn. When I try to check out on their profile, the connections, only the mutual connections appear. I have had a discussion with him and he has made this information visible to all.

This happens with many of my connections. 
I wanted to know some particular reasons for that and the possibile solutions to that. Currently I have some 1500+ connections

Answer (score 3):

From LinkedIn help (italics are mine):

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/52

By default, your 1st-degree connections can see your list of connections. This lets them browse your network and find mutual friends and colleagues. No matter which setting you select, *your 1st-degree connections will always be able to see shared connections*.

https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/4820

Your connection may choose to *hide connections they don't want to share*. In this case, there won't be a See connections option on the member's profile.

---

TL;DR

It's a LinkedIn feature. Your connections can choose whether they wish to reveal NON-SHARED connections or not. Within **Settings > Who can see your connections**, they can select one of two options in the dropdown:

- You *(so no one can see the non-shared connections)*
- Your connections

When you asked your connection to make the change, he changed the preference from the 1st option to the 2nd.

Note: You cannot hide **shared** connections from your 1st degree connections.

Comment: "You cannot hide shared connections from your 1st degree connections."
This is a privacy issue on LinkedIn, like on Instagram. People who want to hide a connection have to remove it.